# getting a substring from each element of a list

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a list of filter facets. I've loaded all the `<span>` in to a list with bs4 and now need to grab a specific substring out of the larger string that is the `<span>`. I want to load each filter facet name in to a list to end up with a list that looks like this: `[size, width, colour, etc]`.

list generated with bs4

```py
[<span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Size" data-v-05f803b1="">Size</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Width" data-v-05f803b1="">Width</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Colour" data-v-05f803b1="">Colour</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Heel Height" data-v-05f803b1="">Heel Height</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Product Type" data-v-05f803b1="">Product Type</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Function" data-v-05f803b1="">Function</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Age" data-v-05f803b1="">Age</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Technology" data-v-05f803b1="">Technology</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Material" data-v-05f803b1="">Material</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Price" data-v-05f803b1="">Price</span>]
```

what I've tried and doesn't seem to get me anywhere:

```py
facetcode = [str(i) for i in spans]

facets = []

for i in facetcode:
    facetcode1 = i.split(' ')
    for y in facetcode1:
        if 'data-facet-name' == True:
            print(y)
```

when I `print(y)` it give me a blank list but I'm expecting something like: `data-facet-name="Size"`

The result I want:

```py
[size, width, colour, etc]
```

Am I over complicating this? The idea is to iterate over each list element and load only the text I want in to a new list.

Comment: Converting to string and then parsing those strings seems like totally the wrong approach. You have a structured markup language there; use a tool which understands its structure instead of writing your own ad hoc parser.

Comment: This is one of the best first posts I've seen in a while! Well done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be missing some of the power of BS4!

```py
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('''<span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Size" data-v-05f803b1="">Size</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Width" data-v-05f803b1="">Width</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Colour" data-v-05f803b1="">Colour</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Heel Height" data-v-05f803b1="">Heel Height</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Product Type" data-v-05f803b1="">Product Type</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Function" data-v-05f803b1="">Function</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Age" data-v-05f803b1="">Age</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Technology" data-v-05f803b1="">Technology</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Material" data-v-05f803b1="">Material</span>, <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Price" data-v-05f803b1="">Price</span>''', 'html.parser')

for span in soup.find_all('span', **{'data-facet-name': True}):
    print(span['data-facet-name'])
```

Comment: I think you're right! thanks for taking a moment to teach. ```facets = []
for span in soup.findAll('span', **{'data-facet-name': True}):
    facets.append(span['data-facet-name'])
print (facets)```

Answer (score 2):

You want to extract the attribute `data-facet-name` from the span's that have that attribute. If you really want a list you can convert the set to a list after.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Size" data-v-05f803b1="">Size</span>, 
  <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Width" data-v-05f803b1="">Width</span>, 
  <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Colour" data-v-05f803b1="">Colour</span>, 
  <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Heel Height" data-v-05f803b1="">Heel Height</span>, 
  <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Product Type" data-v-05f803b1="">Product Type</span>, 
  <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Function" data-v-05f803b1="">Function</span>, 
  <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Age" data-v-05f803b1="">Age</span>, 
  <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Technology" data-v-05f803b1="">Technology</span>, 
  <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Material" data-v-05f803b1="">Material</span>, 
  <span class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9 facet-menu-facet__filter-name-spacing" data-facet-name="Price" data-v-05f803b1="">Price</span>
 </body>
</html>
  '''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml') #or 'html.parser'
print({i['data-facet-name'] for i in soup.select('span[data-facet-name]')})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works! What is causing the printed result to be in a different order than the spans in the html?

Comment: Sets don’t have order. You could just use a list comprehension then do unique on it I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a greedy list comprehension, assuming your data is in a list named `bs4_arr`:

```
attributes = ['='.join(word.split('=')[1:]).strip('"') for word in bs4_arr.split() if word.split('=')[0] == 'data-facet-name']
```

**Here's what it's doing:**

- iterate through every word in your HTML list
- split the word on `=`
- if the attribute name is `data-facet-name`, then we append the attribute value to our result

This is greedy because it calls `word.split('=')` twice.

You can do it without a list comprehension, as well (less greedy):

```
attributes = []
for word in bs4_arr.split():
    tokens = word.split('=')
    name = tokens[0]
    value = '='.join(tokens[1:]).strip('"')
    if name == 'data-facet-name':
         attributes.append(value)
```

A better approach, however, would be to continue using `BeautifulSoup` to parse your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing y only when the string `"data-facet-name"` is equal to `True`, which it never is. I *think* you want that line to be `if y == "data-facet-name"`.